# DMV/DMX: How to get Measure's Folder and subfolders name?

Tags: t-sql, ssas, mdx

As the question says, how can I list all the measures, folder and subsolder?
By looking on msdn I can't find any way to do thet, this is what I'm able to achieve so far, any help?

```
 SELECT
[CATALOG_NAME] AS SSAS_Database_Name,
[CUBE_NAME] AS Cube_or_Perspective_Name,
[MEASUREGROUP_NAME] AS MeasureGroup_Name,
[MEASURE_NAME] AS Measure_Name,
[MEASURE_Caption] AS Measure_Caption,
[MEASURE_IS_VISIBLE] AS Dimension_Visible,
[MEASURE_AGGREGATOR] AS Measure_Aggregator,
[DEFAULT_FORMAT_STRING] AS [Format_String],
[EXPRESSION] AS Calculated_Measure_Expression
FROM
$SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES
ORDER BY
[MEASURE_NAME]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by using:

```
MEASURE_DISPLAY_FOLDER
```

For further reference I managed to find the proper MSDN articole:

[MDSCHEMA_MEASURES Rowset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/schema-rowsets/ole-db-olap/mdschema-measures-rowset)